# error while play youtube video android studio

Tags: java, android

let me say i have listview of many youtube videos, i chosen 1 video from list by videoId. so this id has been passed in second activity, when i declare it. not work..

```
String videoId;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            videoId = extras.getString("videoId");
        }

    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);
    youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
            
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("uuvFkS7LTUk" , 0); // this work.
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId , 0); // this not work.
        }
    });
```

i faced same problem if i play that url use webview youtube embed link....

> There is no error message

***videoid*** = youtube video id example :

youtube.com/watch?v=MIy070Di10U (video id : MIy070Di10U)

image [image: There is no error message]

Comment: So what is the actual value in `videoId`?

Comment: Please check your logcat and attach wrong message on post.

Comment: So `videoId` actually contains a URL?  Then you need to extract the id from it the URL.  You could do it using simple pattern matching, or by parsing the URL and extracting the query parameter with name `"v"`.  That `loadVideo` method should be called with a valid id NOT a URL.   See https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong in your codes, snice u read documentation:

[Documentation](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#api-documentation.)

YouTubePlayer, Params:

> videoId - id of the video

> startSeconds - the time from which the video should start playing

```
loadVideo(videoId: String, startSeconds: Float)
```

make sure u passing Data without subtract, this mistake i made before.

Comment: i missed some parameter while passing data...